# Can't figure out why this output formatting loop is going infinite

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to take in a number from user input, determine whether or not it is prime, and then if it is not, output the factors of the entered number, 5 to a line. The 5 to the line part is where everything goes haywire, the loop i wrote should work fine as far as i can tell, however no matter how much i change it around, it does one of two things, 1) goes infinite with either new lines or the first factor, or 2) outputs a line with 5 of each factor. Here's the code:

```
 else
      {
          cout << "\nNumber is not prime, it's factors are:\n";
           for (int x = 2; x < num; x++)
          {

              factor=num%x;
              if (factor==0)
               {
                  int t=0;
                   cout << x << "\t";
                   t++;

                  for (int t; t <= 5; t++) // THE TROUBLE LOOP
                      {
                          if(t>=5)
                         {
                        t=0;
                        cout << endl;
                         }
                      }
               }

          }
      }
```

Comment: Please don't abuse apostrophes:  The proper grammar is "its factors are:"

Answer (score 7):

Replace the declaration of `t` in the loop since you've declared `t` prior to the loop:

```
for(; t <= 5; t++)
```

With `int t` in the loop declaration you are overriding `t` as an uninitialized variable that will have a garbage value.

Outside of this problem your loop is infinite since you will be resetting `t` to `0` whenever it equals `5`.

Comment: Still goes infinite after building and compiling.

Comment: @user3525452: As I mentioned at the end of my answer there is something wrong with your logic in that loop as it will always be infinite.  If you could elaborate on what it is supposed to do I may be able to help more.

Comment: what the first loop does is goes through and tests the input number as prime or not, and then puts out factors if the number is non prime, the loop that is going infinite is simply supposed to go to a new line after 5 factors are output.

Comment: @user3525452: You shouldn't need a loop to do that.  You should have some kind of a counter and check to see if that is `5`, if so, print a new line and reset the counter.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop change the

```
int t
```

to

```
t=0
```

it is the

```
for(int t,t<=5,t++)
```

the `int t` part in particular that is causing the issue.

Comment: You are repeating the answer given by GWW.  I don't see any additional content.

Comment: Yea, The answer wasn't posted as I was typing

Answer (score 0):

@GGW

Or this:

```
    int t = 0;
    //some code
    for(t; t <= 5; t++)
    //more code
```

Comment: Still goes infinite after building and compiling.

Comment: Even if you put the "int t = 0;" out of the loop? like:                  else
{
    int t = 0;
    //Code
    for(t; t <= 5; t++)
    //Code